# FlywayAutoConfiguration & QuartzAutoConfiguration process order issue

Tags: flyway, quartz

I am using `spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE` and try to use flyway handling the quartz schema initialization, but it seems `QuartzAutoConfiguration` is always processed ahead of `FlywayAutoConfiguration`, which will raise the `[org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve job: ORA-00942]` exception, because the quartz schema is not initialized yet（I am using `jdbc` as the quartz job store type, `spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc`）.

So, am I got something wrong? any idea.

Thanks!!

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17528

Answer (score 0):

it is a bug ,waiting for fix!
please chcek [https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17528]